# Searching for specific data in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagrid

I have to work on a project that has a **datagridview without a datasource.** Also it's done in vb.net. I want to loop through each row on a specific column to find specific data and set my focus on that record.

```
For Each item As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row In myDataGrid.Rows
    ' something like searchFor/contains 
    ' (no idea, can't find the right way to search) for mySpecificData
Next
```

Help is appreciated, best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using **component One FlexGrid**, so I had a look at the **documentation** at [the according site](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/#!XMLDocuments/C1FlexRef/html/AllMembers_T_C1_Win_C1FlexGrid_Row.htm). Each row has an **Item Property** so this example might work

```
For Each row As C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row In myDataGrid.Rows
    if row.Item("COLUMNNAME") = YOUR_VALUE then
        ' select range
        C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Select(row.Index, COLUMN_INDEX);
    end if    
Next
```

If you'd like to directly access a cell you may use [Select method](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1flexgrid/default.htm#!XMLDocuments/C1FlexRef/html/M_C1_Win_C1FlexGrid_C1FlexGridBase_GetUserData_2_fdad1945.htm) instead.

Comment: Your code looked good to me, but unfortunately row.Item("columnname") gives me the column name. I believe the problem will be the "C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.Row" and the "myDataGrid.Rows". but i am not sure

Comment: Sry I don't understand what you meant. row.Item("COLUMNNAME") = xxx may set or get the value of the cell in the given column - at least that's what the docu says...

Comment: Ye before i entered the code, i looked it up aswell - So I was excited that it would have worked, but it didn't =/    I am giving my column index into that method and it gives back the column name.

Comment: perhaps you should check the rowIndex too. imo the first row is the header row so you get the column name

Comment: Wait you are right, let me check that out. Almost 100% this will work. brb